# Showing a DevExpress AspxPopUpControl when user clicks a button

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have added a [`aspxpopupcontrol`](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Popup/) to my website.

I want to show this pop when a user clicks a button. I don't know how to invoke the controller.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to show the ASPxPopupControl - using the server side and client side code.  To show the ASPxPopupControl from the server code, set the ASPxPopupControl.ShowOnPageLoad property to true.  To invoke the ASPxPopupControl from a client side code, call the ASPxPopupControl's Show method.  The [How to show the ASPxPopupControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E55.aspx) example demonstrates both ways.