# How to show devexpress popup control inside a user control from client side

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am using devExpress 11.2 and ASP.NET 4.0. Please bear with me for lengthy problem description.

I have created a user control which contains a ASPxPopupControl (ID = "myPopup")

```
        <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="myPopup" runat="server" ... </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

and other controls. I also implemented a public method ShowPopup() in which it executes the myPopup.ShowOnPageLoad = true in order to show this popup. This user control is then registered and referenced in my ASPX page. I put this user control into a cell of a table within ASPxRoundPanel with ID="myUC"

In this page, I have a ASPxGridView in which I created a custom command button as follows:

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn  VisibleIndex="0" Width="30px" Caption="" ButtonType="Image">
    <CustomButtons>
       <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="cmd">
           <Image Url="~/Images/OK.png" />
       </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
    </CustomButtons>
</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

ClientSideEvents is defined as

```
<ClientSideEvents BeginCallback="OnDevExpressBeginCallback" EndCallback="OnDevExpressEndCallback">
```

I would like to popup my user control when this image button is clicked. Please note that this ASPxGridView also provide Insert/Editing/Delete function.

There are two ways to deal with this requirement.

1  In order to ensure ASPxGridView handling its built-in commands (Insert and etc) correctly, I need to set `EnableCallBacks="True"` then I set  `OnCustomButtonCallback="OnmyASPxGridView_CustomButtonCallback"` to handle the clicking event of the image button from code behind. I called myUC.ShowPopup() from code behind and I debugged up to here. However, the popup is not shown. If I set `EnableCallBacks="False"` then the popup is shown exactly what I expected.

The problem of this approach is not acceptable because the built-in commands do not work properly. So the question is how can I show the popup control within my user control from code behind while `EnableCallBacks="True"` ?

2 Second approach is to show popup from client side.
I set `EnableCallBacks="True"` first to ensure my built-in commands work properly. then I defined ClientSideEvents as

```
<ClientSideEvents BeginCallback="OnDevExpressBeginCallback" EndCallback="OnDevExpressEndCallback" CustomButtonClick="jsfnShowPopUpControl"/>
```

and removed OnCustomButtonCallback event.

I implemented javascript function jsfnShowPopUpControl like this:

```
function jsfnShowPopUpControl(s, e) {
    // next, find access control inside user control
    **var myPopupName = document.getElementById('<%=myUC.FindControl("myPopup").ClientID %>');**

    if (myPopupName != null) {
        myPopupName.Show();
        myPopupName.PerformCallback(e);
    }
    else {
        alert("Data error encountered"); // cannot find popup
        return; //  
    }}
```

The key part of this approach is to find the devexpress popup control which resides within a user control. Unfortunately that getElementById function could not find the underneath control in my user control and thus popup is not shown either.

Please help and let me know what I did wrong in my two different approaches.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Reference these- [Showing a DevExpress AspxPopUpControl when user clicks a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195545/showing-a-devexpress-aspxpopupcontrol-when-user-clicks-a-button)

[How to show ASPxPopupControl's window on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q519476)

To solve this issue, I suggest you use the [ASPxClientPopupControl.ShowWindow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupControl_ShowWindowtopic) method.

> For this same scanerio as you want to implement what i have done.
>   Assigned ClientInstanceName property to some unique name on the page
>   including the user control now you free to access that object anywhere
>   in the html through javascript.

Let you set the popup's ClientInstanceName to "MainASPxClientPopupControl". Thus, it should be possible to use it on you main page as follows:

```
MainASPxClientPopupControl.Show();
```

Reference on this topic: [ASPxPopupControl - Cannot get an instance of the popup from a page](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q531435)

Comment: Thanks for the info from Niranjan. I am not familiar with  ASPxClientPopupControl and will take a look at it later. There is one part that I missed mention is that the main reason using getElementById in my javascript to find popup control instead of using ClientInstanceName which can show the popup is because the ClientInstanceName is global, and I have to create dynamic names for multiple user controls of the popup in the same page. So the key question now is how getElementById  can find the handler of the devexpress popup control within a user control. Thanks